# Sorting lists with keys vba

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I am writing something to sort the data between A2 and the end of the data in F. The sort will first sort F using a custom array order, then sort A alphabetically within the F order. At the moment i'm getting the error "Expected end of statement" for Key1 but i'm not sure why this is. is there something i'm missing to be able to use sort keys?

```
Sub Sort_Data()

Dim lstrw As Integer


    lstrw = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row

    With  Range("A2", Cells(lstrw, "F")).Sort Key1:=Range("F2"), CustomOrder1:="OFDB,CSTM,*FS", _
           key2:=Range("A2"), order2:=xlAscending, _
           Header:=xlNo
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `.Sort` down to the next line:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sort_Data()
    Dim lstrw As Integer
    lstrw = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
    With Range("A2", Cells(lstrw, "F"))
        .Sort Key1:=Range("F2"), CustomOrder1:="OFDB,CSTM,*FS", _
           key2:=Range("A2"), order2:=xlAscending, _
           Header:=xlNo
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Now it's moved onto named argument not found for "CustomOrder"? also why did .sort have to be the next line?

Comment: It's `Order1`, not "CustomOrder1". [MSDN Range.Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646.aspx)

Comment: Changing to order yields the error "overflow". which I would assume to be down to missmatched ranges but I can't see anything wrong on that side?

Comment: I suggest working out the sort by hand on the worksheet and recording a macro. Then use the information in that recorded macro to properly set up your own vba. You can even define the custom sort order using the ribbon controls if necesary.